# Complex data transformation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

My dataset looks like this : https://www.dropbox.com/s/u4brzjnhac0pwnj/TEST.xlsx?dl=0

I need to convert the data in the original table to the one in the desired table, in the attached file.

I have a set of household_ids(HH) with data across months 1-7 for each household, I want that for every HH/month i have data corresponding to the previous 3 months, placed adjacent to this record and in the same row. This is to be done for all months for each household.

It is a complex problem to explain in text, and i think a look at the data with be explainatory.

I have written some code for it, which is very ineffient, and iterates through all 5mn records of the dataset. Taking days, can this be done in a more efficient way.

```
    import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(r'H:\shared\tran')

c=pd.read_csv(r'0.csv')


c['_prev1_month_id']=''                     
c['_prev1_tuned_duration']=''               
c['_prev1_weekend_tuned_duration']=''       
c['_prev1_channel_flips']=''                
c['_prev1_most_common_daypart']=''          
c['_prev1_programs_watched_per_hh']=''      
c['_prev1_midnight']=''                     
c['_prev1_morning']=''                      
c['_prev1_afternoon']=''                    
c['_prev1_evening']=''  
c['_prev2_month_id']=''                     
c['_prev2_tuned_duration']=''               
c['_prev2_weekend_tuned_duration']=''       
c['_prev2_channel_flips']=''                
c['_prev2_most_common_daypart']=''          
c['_prev2_programs_watched_per_hh']=''      
c['_prev2_midnight']=''                     
c['_prev2_morning']=''                      
c['_prev2_afternoon']=''                    
c['_prev2_evening']=''                      
c['_prev3_month_id']=''                     
c['_prev3_tuned_duration']=''               
c['_prev3_weekend_tuned_duration']=''       
c['_prev3_channel_flips']=''                
c['_prev3_most_common_daypart']=''          
c['_prev3_programs_watched_per_hh']=''      
c['_prev3_midnight']=''                     
c['_prev3_morning']=''                      
c['_prev3_afternoon']=''                    
c['_prev3_evening']='' 




def tran(v): 

    for i in v.month_id: 
        if i>3:         
            ind=v[v.month_id==i].index[0]   
            j=i-1
            #print ('Doing   m:',j,'  ind:',v[v.month_id==i]['month_id'].get_values()[0])
            print ('index :',ind)
            try:
                c.ix[ind,'_prev1_month_id']=v[v.month_id==j]['month_id'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev1_tuned_duration']=v[v.month_id==j]['tuned_duration'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev1_weekend_tuned_duration']=v[v.month_id==j]['weekend_tuned_duration'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev1_channel_flips']=v[v.month_id==j]['channel_flips'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev1_most_common_daypart']=v[v.month_id==j]['most_common_daypart'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev1_programs_watched_per_hh']=v[v.month_id==j]['most_common_daypart'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev1_midnight']=v[v.month_id==j]['midnight'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev1_morning']=v[v.month_id==j]['morning'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev1_afternoon']=v[v.month_id==j]['afternoon'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev1_evening']=v[v.month_id==j]['evening'].get_values()[0]      
            except :
                #print ('No record found for HH ',v.household_id,' and month ',j)
                pass

            j=j-1
            try:
                c.ix[ind,'_prev2_month_id']=v[v.month_id==j]['month_id'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev2_tuned_duration']=v[v.month_id==j]['tuned_duration'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev2_weekend_tuned_duration']=v[v.month_id==j]['weekend_tuned_duration'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev2_channel_flips']=v[v.month_id==j]['channel_flips'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev2_most_common_daypart']=v[v.month_id==j]['most_common_daypart'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev2_programs_watched_per_hh']=v[v.month_id==j]['most_common_daypart'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev2_midnight']=v[v.month_id==j]['midnight'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev2_morning']=v[v.month_id==j]['morning'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev2_afternoon']=v[v.month_id==j]['afternoon'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev2_evening']=v[v.month_id==j]['evening'].get_values()[0]            
            except:
                #print ('No record found for HH ',v.household_id,' and month ',j)
                pass

            j=j-1
            try:            
                c.ix[ind,'_prev3_month_id']=v[v.month_id==j]['month_id'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev3_tuned_duration']=v[v.month_id==j]['tuned_duration'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev3_weekend_tuned_duration']=v[v.month_id==j]['weekend_tuned_duration'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev3_channel_flips']=v[v.month_id==j]['channel_flips'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev3_most_common_daypart']=v[v.month_id==j]['most_common_daypart'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev3_programs_watched_per_hh']=v[v.month_id==j]['most_common_daypart'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev3_midnight']=v[v.month_id==j]['midnight'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev3_morning']=v[v.month_id==j]['morning'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev3_afternoon']=v[v.month_id==j]['afternoon'].get_values()[0]
                c.ix[ind,'_prev3_evening']=v[v.month_id==j]['evening'].get_values()[0]  
            except:
                pass
                #print ('No record found for HH ',v.household_id,' and month ',j)


        else:
            #print ('Ignored for HH ',v.household_id,' and month ',j)
            pass


z.head()
m=0
for k in z.household_id.unique():
    for i in list(z[z['household_id']==k].month_id):
        if i >3:
            j=i-1

            #index of original row
            ind=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==i)].index[0]
            print ('Doing : hh:',k,'  m:',i,'  ind:',ind)
            try:
                z['_prev1_month_id'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['month_id'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev1_tuned_duration'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['tuned_duration'].get_values()[0]                 
                z['_prev1_weekend_tuned_duration'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['weekend_tuned_duration'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev1_channel_flips'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['channel_flips'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev1_most_common_daypart'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['most_common_daypart'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev1_programs_watched_per_hh'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['programs_watched_per_hh'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev1_midnight'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['midnight'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev1_morning'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['morning'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev1_afternoon'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['afternoon'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev1_evening'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['evening'].get_values()[0] 

            except :
                print ('No record found for HH ',k,' and month ',j)
            j=j-1
            try:
                z['_prev2_month_id'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['month_id'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev3_tuned_duration'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['tuned_duration'].get_values()[0]                 
                z['_prev2_weekend_tuned_duration'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['weekend_tuned_duration'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev2_channel_flips'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['channel_flips'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev2_most_common_daypart'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['most_common_daypart'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev2_programs_watched_per_hh'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['programs_watched_per_hh'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev2_midnight'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['midnight'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev2_morning'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['morning'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev2_afternoon'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['afternoon'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev2_evening'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['evening'].get_values()[0] 

            except:
                print ('No record found for HH ',k,' and month ',j)

            j=j-1
            try:            
                z['_prev3_month_id'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['month_id'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev3_tuned_duration'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['tuned_duration'].get_values()[0]                 
                z['_prev3_weekend_tuned_duration'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['weekend_tuned_duration'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev3_channel_flips'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['channel_flips'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev3_most_common_daypart'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['most_common_daypart'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev3_programs_watched_per_hh'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['programs_watched_per_hh'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev3_midnight'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['midnight'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev3_morning'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['morning'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev3_afternoon'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['afternoon'].get_values()[0] 
                z['_prev3_evening'].ix[ind]=z[(z.household_id==k) & (z.month_id==j)]['evening'].get_values()[0]
            except:
                print ('No record found for HH ',k,' and month ',j)


        else:
            print ('Ignored for HH ',k,' and month ',j)
```

Call the function :

```
#c.groupby('household_id').apply(tran)
```

Comment: Please include such current data and desired result in body of your question. Remember your audience is also for future readers who may not have you available link.

Answer (score 0):

Although i couldnt not do it faster in python, i was able to do it in sql pretty quickly using analytics function.

```
    select month_id, household_id, tuned_duration,weekend_tuned_duration,channel_flips,most_common_daypart,
programs_watched_per_hh,trend,midnight,morning,afternoon,evening,
--rank() over (partition by month_id desc, household_id order by month_id desc desc 
lead (month_id) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as month_id_1,
lead (household_id) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as household_id_1,
lead (tuned_duration) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as tuned_duration_1,
lead (weekend_tuned_duration) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as weekend_tuned_duration_1,
lead (channel_flips) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as channel_flips_1,
lead (most_common_daypart) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as most_common_daypart_1,
lead (programs_watched_per_hh) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as program_watched_per_hh_1,
lead (trend) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as trend_1,
lead (midnight) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as midnight_1,
lead (morning) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as morning_1,
lead (afternoon) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as afternoon_1,
lead (evening) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as evening_1,
lead (month_id,2) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as month_id_2,
lead (household_id,2) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as household_id_2,
lead (tuned_duration,2) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as tuned_duration_2,
lead (weekend_tuned_duration,2) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as weekend_tuned_duration_2,
lead (channel_flips,2) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as channel_flips_2,
lead (most_common_daypart,2) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as most_common_daypart_2,
lead (programs_watched_per_hh,2) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as program_watched_per_hh_2,
lead (trend,2) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as trend_2,
lead (midnight,2) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as midnight_2,
lead (morning,2) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as morning_2,
lead (afternoon,2) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as afternoon_2,
lead (evening,2) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as evening_2,
lead (month_id,3) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as month_id_3,
lead (household_id,3) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as household_id_3,
lead (tuned_duration,3) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as tuned_duration_3,
lead (weekend_tuned_duration,3) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as weekend_tuned_duration_3,
lead (channel_flips,3) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as channel_flips_3,
lead (most_common_daypart,3) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as most_common_daypart_3,
lead (programs_watched_per_hh,3) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as program_watched_per_hh_3,
lead (trend,3) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as trend_3,
lead (midnight,3) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as midnight_3,
lead (morning,3) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as morning_3,
lead (afternoon,3) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as afternoon_3,
lead (evening,3) over (partition by household_id order by month_id desc) as evening_3
from
 table
```